# Can a kosher restaurant play music for its diners?

Tags: halacha, sources-mekorot, music, restaurant

I was told by Rabbi Yehezkel Danziger, an editor at Art Scroll (he was editor in chief of most of the volumes of the Shottenstein Talmud Bavli) that it is forbidden to listen to music while eating, because we are in mourning for the destruction of the Temple.  He asked me (rhetorically) how do rabbinic councils give hasghacha to restaurants that play recorded or live music to their patrons while they eat?  What is the source for this prohibition?  Are there vaad's that actually prohibit music in kosher restaurants?

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/71421/live-music-and-eating-a-meal

Comment: See https://www.sefaria.org/Kitzur_Shulchan_Aruch.126.3?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en for one modern(ish) source. Regarding how Va'adim allow that in restaurants, that probably falls under the greater debate as to what role the Hshgacha plays in the broader ambience of the establishment (i.e. are they certifying the entire establishment, or just the food?  Should they also insist upon a dress code for the servers, no TV (or WiFi?) in the building, properly educating consumers about 'hard cheese', etc?).

Comment: http://halachipedia.com/index.php?title=Listening_to_Music#cite_ref-6

Comment: This is a great question. But @Salmonius's comment seems to raise 2 aspects that, perhaps, may require that this question be "split". - 1) Is music playing allowed - at all & (for this question) in restaurants? and 2) What is the role of the Va'ad regarding restaurants.

Comment: @DanF Re: #1: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/2169/music-not-allowed-the-whole-year . Re: #2: I was sure I'd seen a question asking about the extent of a Hashgacha's obligations with regards to the restaurant as a whole, but I may be confusing it with a [Coffee Room Thread](https://www.theyeshivaworld.com/coffeeroom/topic/hechsher)